# Set PIC flag for asm compiling

Tags: assembly, gcc, shared-libraries, x86-64, dynamic-linking

How to set PIC flag for asm compiling by assembler in GCC build ?

```
  gcc -shared -o u.o -fPIC u.asm -Wa .....
```

will fail, what's correct solution ?
**Edit**
as a matter of fact, I actually have nothing to do with this case/knowledge. I just need to make my own libffmpeg.so as this https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu only for static binary build instruction.
So tried add -fPIC for each on it and sum them all up by running
`gcc -shared -o libffmpeg.so -Wl,--whole-archive lib/lib*.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive`
thanks God all went smoothly except such error of this case

```
/usr/bin/ld: lib/libx265.a(cpu-a.asm.o): relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol x265_intel_cpu_indicator_init' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC    
/usr/bin/ld: lib/libx265.a(pixel-util8.asm.o): relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol x265_entropyStateBits' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
```

So my last straw just guess which closest to the actual problem as such above

Comment: What would you expect this flag to do?  Either you wrote the asm to be position-independent or you didn't, and if you didn't, the assembler can't do anything to fix it.

Comment: The `R_X86_64_PC32` error suggests you are generating 64-bit code and the linker realizes you have an instruction that uses a absolute address that may not be enough to represented as a 32-bit absolute address. GCC thinks your code may have been generate by the GCC tool chain and offers an option to re-compile with `-fpic` or `-fPIC`. This doesn't apply to hand generated assembly. You have to make the assembly code position independent.

Comment: A way to get such a relocation is if you have a label like `message` and attempt to do `mov $message, %rax`. You could make this position independent and work with a 64-bit shared object using RIP elative addressing with something like `lea message(%rip), %rax`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "recompile with `-fPIC`" message is misleading in this case.  The message assumes that the offending object file was compiled from C/C++ source, in which case `-fPIC` would cause the compiler to generate position-independent assembly code.  But this is just a guess, as the linker doesn't actually know how the file was produced, and in this case, the file was assembled from handwritten assembly.  `-fPIC` can't help with that; it is a compiler flag and this code is never compiled.  The assembly code has to be hand-rewritten to be position independent, i.e. not use absolute addresses anywhere.

Unless the code is doing something pretty unusual, this would be a routine task for someone familiar with assembly language, but maybe a bit of a project for someone who isn't.  There are a few different things that one has to watch for, and I don't know if there is a guide explaining them all in one place.

It is also possible that someone has already written a position-independent version of this file, or maybe there are `#ifdef`s to select position-independent code which has been written.  I haven't looked at the file myself. You should probably do some research to see if there's existing support for compiling this library as a shared library; it may be that there is and you're just not doing it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

> will fail

What's the exact error message?

If I try your command line, my GCC version complains about the extension `.asm` because it does not know which file type this is. Assembly language files in GCC are typically named `.s` (lower case; not `.asm`);

or `.S` (uppercase) if the Assembly code shall be pre-processed using the C preprocessor (so C preprocessor statements like `#define`, `#include`, `#ifdef`, `#if` etc. can be used in the Assembly code).

I also assume that your command line contains "`-c`"; otherwise the command line will try to compile **and link** instead of only compiling.

> How to set PIC flag for asm compiling by assembler in GCC build ?

As Nate Eldredge already wrote, this is not possible:

`-fPIC` is telling the compiler how C (or C++, Fortran ...) code is translated **to** Assembly code.

If you already have Assembly code, it is either position-dependend or position-independent.

So the correct question would be: "How to write Assembly code for x86-32 *(or whatever architecture)* in a way that it is position-independent?"